# Convolution over two images using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I have an image tensor of shape `(128,128,6)`. It contains two images stacked along the **third dimension** (2x3=6 channels). Now I would like to use convolution over that dimension such that I get a (128,128,3) Tensor which I can use as an input to a pretrained model (for example vgg16) using Keras.

The two images can be seen as adjacent frames of a video. The goal is to gain information about the change between the first and the second image (find some local correlation between the images)

How can I perform such a convolution where I either use (for example) a `5x5x6` kernel. Or alternatively I could convolve the respective channels of each image with a `5x5x2`kernel (convolve the red,green,blue channels of both images separately).

How would I implement this in Keras or native Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use three inputs, where I use two images in each. Then you can just use a standard convolution like this: `Convolution2D(1, 5, 5, border_mode='same')` seperate for each input to achieve the desired result. Afterwards you can merge them with a merge layer and feed the resulting image into the pre trained network.

In all that would look like this for tensorflow dim_ordering:

```
inp1 = Input((128,128,2))
cv1 = Convolution2D(1, 5, 5, border_mode='same')
inp2 = Input((128,128, 2))
...
model_input = merge([cv1, cv2, cv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
```